# How to whitelist User Agent for Shopware 5

Tags: user-agent, shopware, shopware5

For another service, which needs to download images from Shopware 5, I was asked to whitelist their header. But I can't find any hint how to do that in Shopware 5.

They provided me this line:

```
headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; xxx-Images)', 'X-xxx-Whitelist': 'xxx-Images', }
```

Can anyone provide me some help or tell me where I can read about it?

Comment: You are managing the Shopware 5 site, right? And the other service sends this header? Is the "xxx" redacted by you or is it really the string "xxx" ? Normally the download should already work. Is the other service running in some rate limits because of downloading too many images? Please update your questions with some more information / and error messages if you get such.

Comment: Also let us know, which URLs are being downloaded. Is it possible that there is some additional webserver module in place, like a firewall (mod_security for example) or DOS protection (mod_evasive for example)